# Find and draw the largest contour in opencv on a specific color (Python)

Tags: python, draw, contour

Im trying to get the largest contour of a red book.
I've got a little problem with the code because its getting the contours of the smallest objects (blobs) instead of the largest one and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening

The code I use:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)

while True:
    #Loading Camera
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    blurred = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(frame, 3, 3)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_range = np.array([150, 10, 10])
    upper_range = np.array([180, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

    dilation = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)

    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    #Getting the edge of morphology
    edge = cv2.Canny(closing, 175, 175)
    _, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edge, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Find the index of the largest contour
    areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
    max_index = np.argmax(areas)
    cnt=contours[max_index]

    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)


    cv2.imshow('threshold', frame)
    cv2.imshow('edge', edge)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break


camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[As you can see on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyGo.png)

Hopefully there is someone who can help

Comment: I just tried to test it when the book had no blobs in it, Then I saw that it drew a contour around the whole book (sometimes). So my question now will be how can I draw a contour around the book even when it has some blobs in it?

Comment: So does it needs to be a red book? Or it can be with other colors?

Comment: Eventually I need to use this method to detect a circle on the ground and on other different objects. Thats why I use a red book as an example

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can start by defining a **mask** in the range of the **red** tones of the book you are looking for.

Then you can just find the contour with the **biggest area** and draw the rectangular shape of the book.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the image
image = cv2.imread("path_to_your_image.png", 1)

# red color boundaries [B, G, R]
lower = [1, 0, 20]
upper = [60, 40, 220]

# create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
# the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 40, 255, 0)
if (cv2.__version__[0] > 3):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
else:
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    # draw in blue the contours that were founded
    cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1, 255, 3)

    # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # draw the biggest contour (c) in green
    cv2.rectangle(output,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("Result", np.hstack([image, output]))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Using your image:

[image]

If you want the book to rotate you can use `rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)` as you can find it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

**Edit**:

You should also consider other colour spaces beside the RGB, as the HSV or HLS. Usually, people use the HSV since the H channel stays fairly consistent in shadow or excessive brightness. In other words, you should get better results if you use the HSV colourspace.

[image]

In specific, in OpenCV the Hue range is `[0,179]`. In the following figure (made by [@Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3547485/kinght-%e9%87%91)), you can find a 2D slice of that cylinder, in `V = 255`, where the horizontal axis is the `H` and the vertical axis the `S`. As you can see from that figure to capture the red you need both to include the lower (e.g., H=0 to H=10) and upper region (e.g., H=170 to H=179) of the Hue values.

[image]

Comment: This works exactly how it needs to detect an object with color. I switched your code back to the camera. The only thing I need to focus on is the reflection/shadow range (of the color) so it constanly picking up the object.
Thank you so much for your time. Sadly the upvote is not visible on this post.

Comment: @Zaptimist your welcome! If you need something comment here and I will help if I know

Comment: I've got a slight problem in some cases,
Im getting this error when the object is too big:

c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Doest this mean it could not find a contour for the color red?

Comment: It seems when it tries to draw a very small rectangle the program crashes and getting the "max() arg is an empty sequence" error message, In the image you can see the green dot [link to image](https://gyazo.com/17de789ba2976eb7c1846604b3d5003f) @João Cartucho

Comment: @Zaptimist I edited the code. It was failing when there were no contours as you said, so we can add a if case to check it

Comment: Thats the check where I was looking for. The check is so simple and still I couldn't find it haha, Thanks again. Hopefully I can do my work without asking more questions ;)

Comment: What exactly is `c` here? I tried to print and it printed a matrix in a matrix.

Comment: @Schütze it's a contour

Comment: @JoãoCartucho A bit late to the party but: When I draw `c` with `cv2.drawContours()` I only get an unevenly dotted line as the contour while I get nice smooth lines when I draw `contours`. Is this an expected result? And is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @GittingGud in the code I am drawing `contours` with `cv2.drawContours()` and not `c`.

Comment: @JoãoCartucho Yes and that works perfectly for me as well, but I only want to draw the biggest contour. Therefore I tried to draw `c` with `cv2.drawContours()` but it's only unevenly dotted.  I just wanted to know if there's a fix for that but as it is not really a part of the original question its not important.

Comment: A contour is a list of points that represent a curve in an image.

Comment: @JoãoCartucho how did you determine the red boundaries?

Comment: for the HSV or RGB colourspace? But for both, if you can simply do a `imshow` and have a look at the values

Comment: I think you intended `int(cv2.__version__.split(".")[0]) > 3` for your first if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to convert Grayscale masks to Rectangles

```
def mask_to_rect(image):
    '''
    
        Give rectangle cordinates according to the mask image
        
        
        Params: image : (numpy.array) Gray Scale Image
        
        Returns: Cordinates : (list) List of cordinates [x, y, w h]
    
    '''
    
    # Getting the Thresholds and ret
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 1, 0)
    
    # Checking the version of open cv I tried for (version 4)
    #    Getting contours on the bases of thresh
    if (int(cv2.__version__[0]) > 3):
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    else:
        im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    
    # Getting the biggest contour
    if len(contours) != 0:
        # draw in blue the contours that were founded
        cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1, 255, 3)

        # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
        c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        
    return [x, y, w, h]
```

Result

[image]