# Python OpenCV finding the biggest contour

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have a problem while looking for biggest contour. I'm using image after canny edge detection:
[image: Canny edge detection]

Then I'm using

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

to find contours:

[image: Contour detection]

Next step is to find the biggest contour...
I've tried:

```
contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
```

but this give me something like:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

**Code:**

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('TEST_1.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
edges = cv2.Canny(gaussian,100,200)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

contourImg = cv2.drawContours(image, contour, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Contours", contourImg)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also, contour area for this dot is 109 and for my biggest contour is 3.5

Comment: `contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)` seems OK to me. What are you doing after that? Can you please attach the next code snippet as well ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and draw the largest contour in opencv on a specific color (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588279/find-and-draw-the-largest-contour-in-opencv-on-a-specific-color-python)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk As you can see I've already used this code.

Comment: @ZdaR Maybe problem is in that contour is not closed? I used `contourImg = cv2.drawContours(image, [max(contours, key = len)], 0, (0,255,0),2, cv2.LINE_AA, maxLevel=1)` and it's working.

Comment: If you wanna go with area then use dilate and closing morphological operation before finding out the contours.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it seems like some contours are not closed. Using length as criterion rather than area in this case worked for me.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('TEST_1.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
edges = cv2.Canny(gaussian,100,200)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contour = max(contours, key = len)

contourImg = cv2.drawContours(image, contour, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Contours", contourImg)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also changed the method in findContours from cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE to cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE.
Alternately, you try fixing the problem by changing the limit values in cv2.Canny() and using cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL.